# IIS rewrite rule with Tomcat 9.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, iis, url-rewriting

I have deployed a Spring Boot application in Tomcat in Windows Server and it's accessible on browser via http://server-name:8080/app. Now, for end users I don't want them to hit the app at port 8080, so I have configured an IIS rewrite rule

```xml
<rule name="app" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url="^app.*" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://server-name:8080/{R:0}" logRewriteUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

Now, when I hit http://server-name/app, it works, but the subsequent calls are going to http://server-name:8080/app.

I am not sure if there is a problem with the IIS rule since I ran the app.war using same application.properties as

```bash
java -jar app.war --server.port=8080 --spring.config.import=application.properties
```

The only caveat here is I am passing context path in properties as

```
server.servlet.context-path=/app
```

and in this scenario all the URL calls go without port 8080. If anyone have any insight or solution, please share.

**Please NOTE**: I can't host Tomcat on port 80 as there are other apps running on port 80 which uses the API from app deployed in Tomcat.

Comment: You should use HttpPlatformHandler to host Java web apps on IIS, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-release-of-the-httpplatformhandler-module-for-iis-8/

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for the reply, I am not hosting java apps on IIS, I am hosting it on Tomcat containers and leveraging IIS rewrite rule to access app at port 80 instead of Tomcat's port 8080. Also I can't host Tomcat on port 80 as there are other apps running on port 80 which uses the API from app deployed in Tomcat.

Comment: You do need to read that article and see what I was talking about. IIS is powerful enough to allow multiple web apps/sites to run at port 80, so I wonder why you cannot let it serve you in the best possible way.

Comment: @LexLi - Sure, I am reading it now. Will implement and check if serves the purpose. Thanks alot for your suggestion.

Comment: @LexLi - I have tried this and it works fine, but I don't want my product to depend on additional module other than default. I will keep trying other solution and post the update here in case I got the solution to the issue. Thanks for your recommendation.

Comment: Out-of-band IIS components (URL Rewrite/HttpPlatformHandler) are under the same support policies, usually considered part of Windows/IIS. Thus, "I don't want my product to depend on additional module other than default" is an unnecessary concern. Most IIS administrators should be familiar with them (since IIS 7).

Comment: @LexLi - I completely agree with you. I will use it in our development environment and once security team qualifies to be deployable in prod then we can go with it. Thanks.